# How to add centered background using css

Tags: html, css, background

I want to use this kind of image for my background.
http://www.wallpaperpin.com/xres/1920x1440-download-free-awesome-psd-designs-website-backgrounds.jpg
How can I make it look "centered" (I mean the light rays to be displayed as if they are in the middle of the site) using css on any screen resolution it will be browsed? I mean to be displayed in the same way both on 1440x1050 or 1920x1080 or on any mobile device.

Do I have to find other pictures with other resolutions to be displayed depending on the visitor's resolution? Will that require php-script?

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
   background: url("imageurl.jpg") center center;
}
```

If you want it to scale to the browser resolution, you can also use

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Will that it make it look the same way viewed on any screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

```
background              : url('images/background.jpg') top center no-repeat
background-size         : 100%;
```

making it top center rather than center center makes it from the top... (Duh) and background-size: 100% makes the image the size of the browser window.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! But what if it has to be repeated, but starting from the red line as shown on the screenshot? http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/4707/wjm7.png